# Cappuccino - CPSplitView fixed subviews' size

Tags: javascript, objective-c, user-interface, cappuccino, objective-j

I have a class `GridNode` inheriting from `CPSplitView` that is used to wrap objects of type `GridELement`. Each consecutive split of a `GridNode` divides it into two new `GridNodes` (containing `GridElements` that resize with their parent).

Another class - `GridToolbar` inherits from `GridElement`. It should basically have the same behaviour as `GridElement` although the size shouldn't change automatically (as the container is resized) but only after user drags the splitter.

The problem is, even if I set the `AutoresizingMask` to a specific direction (as the toolbars can be either vertical or horizontal) it still gets resized in both of them.

Any suggestions on what I can do to prevent this from happening?

source of **GridNode.j**:

```
@implementation GridNode : CPSplitView
{
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aFrame
{
  self = [super initWithFrame:aFrame];

  if(self)
  {
    [self setAutoresizingMask:CPViewWidthSizable | CPViewHeightSizable ];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[CPColor colorWithHexString:"EEEEEE"]]
  }

  return self;
}

- (void)split:(id)sender
{
  var parent = [sender superview];

  var gridNode = [
    [GridNode alloc]
    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(
      0, 0,
      CGRectGetWidth([parent bounds]),
      CGRectGetHeight([parent bounds])
    )
  ];
  [gridNode setVertical:(CGRectGetWidth([gridNode bounds]) >= CGRectGetHeight([gridNode bounds]) ? YES : NO)]

  var element = [
    [GridElement alloc]
    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(
      0, 0,
      CGRectGetWidth([parent bounds]),
      CGRectGetHeight([parent bounds])
    )
  ];

  [self replaceSubview:parent with:gridNode];

  [parent setBtnTarget:gridNode];
  [element setBtnTarget:gridNode];

  [gridNode addSubview:parent];
  [gridNode addSubview:element];
}

- (void)addBar:(id)sender
{
  var parent = [sender superview];

  var gridNode = [
    [GridNode alloc]
    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(
      0, 0,
      CGRectGetWidth([parent bounds]),
      CGRectGetHeight([parent bounds])
    )
  ];
  [gridNode setVertical:(CGRectGetWidth([gridNode bounds]) >= CGRectGetHeight([gridNode bounds]) ? YES : NO)]

  var isVertical = [gridNode isVertical];
  var toolbar = [
    [GridToolbar alloc]
    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(
      0, 0,
      CGRectGetWidth([parent bounds]),
      CGRectGetHeight([parent bounds])
    )
    vertical: isVertical
  ];

  [parent setBounds:CGRectMake(
    isVertical ? 32 : 0, isVertical ? 0 : 32,
    CGRectGetWidth([gridNode bounds]) - (isVertical ? 32 : 0),
    CGRectGetHeight([parent bounds]) - (isVertical ? 0 : 32)
  )];

  [self replaceSubview:parent with:gridNode];

  [parent setBtnTarget:gridNode];
  [toolbar setBtnTarget:gridNode];

  [gridNode addSubview:toolbar];
  [gridNode addSubview:parent];
}

@end
```

source of **GridElement.j**:

```
@implementation GridElement : CPView
{
  CPButton btnSPlit;
  CPButton btnToolbar;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aFrame
{
  self = [super initWithFrame:aFrame]

  if (self)
  {
    [self setAutoresizingMask:CPViewWidthSizable | CPViewHeightSizable ];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[CPColor colorWithCalibratedRed:Math.random() green:Math.random() blue:Math.random() alpha:1.0]];

    btnSPlit = [
        [CPButton alloc]
        initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,128,24)
    ];

    [btnSPlit setAutoresizingMask:CPViewMinXMargin | CPViewMaxXMargin | CPViewMinYMargin | CPViewMaxYMargin];
    [btnSPlit setFrameOrigin:CGPointMake((CGRectGetWidth([self bounds]) - CGRectGetWidth([btnSPlit frame])) / 2.0,
                        (CGRectGetHeight([self bounds]) - CGRectGetHeight([btnSPlit frame])) / 2.0 - 15)];
    [btnSPlit setTitle:"split me!"];

    [btnSPlit setAction:@selector(split:)];

    [self addSubview:btnSPlit]

    btnToolbar = [
        [CPButton alloc]
        initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,128,24)
    ];

    [btnToolbar setAutoresizingMask:CPViewMinXMargin | CPViewMaxXMargin | CPViewMinYMargin | CPViewMaxYMargin];
    [btnToolbar setFrameOrigin:CGPointMake((CGRectGetWidth([self bounds]) - CGRectGetWidth([btnToolbar frame])) / 2.0,
                        (CGRectGetHeight([self bounds]) - CGRectGetHeight([btnToolbar frame])) / 2.0 + 15)];
    [btnToolbar setTitle:"split me!"];

    [btnToolbar setAction:@selector(addBar:)];

    [self addSubview:btnToolbar]
  }

  return self;
}

- (void)setBtnTarget:(id)aTarget
{
  [btnSPlit setTarget:aTarget];
  [btnSPlit setTitle:"split "+aTarget._UID]
  [btnToolbar setTarget:aTarget];
  [btnToolbar setTitle:"toolbar "+aTarget._UID]
}

@end
```

source of **GridToolbar.j**:

```
@implementation GridToolbar : GridElement
{
  CPButtonBar btnBar;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aFrame vertical:(BOOL)isVertical
{
  self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(
    0,0,
    isVertical == NO ? aFrame.size.width : 32,
    isVertical == YES ? aFrame.size.height : 32
  )]

  if(self)
  {
    isVertical == YES ? [self setAutoresizingMask:CPViewWidthSizable] : [self setAutoresizingMask:CPViewHeightSizable];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[CPColor blackColor]];

    btnBar = [
      [CPButtonBar alloc]
      initWithFrame:CGRectMake(
        0,0,
        CGRectGetWidth([self bounds]),
        CGRectGetHeight([self bounds])
      )
    ];
  }

  return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Some screenshots of what this looks like today, maybe with a few arrows showing what it's supposed to look like would make this much faster to understand and help out with.

Comment: Actually I received a useful suggestion [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/objectivej/K9ooJtX6qQM/discussion). Creating my own delegate that is handling the automatic resize of `GridNode`'s subviews according to a fixed value set while dragging the resizer was all I had to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received a useful suggestion [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/objectivej/K9ooJtX6qQM/discussion). Creating my own delegate that is handling the automatic resize of `GridNode`'s subviews according to a fixed value set while dragging the divider was all I had to do.